# How to parse json data based on dynamic id with jquery in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

I need to fetch the country code of the selected country ID from dropdown

I have  ajax call which returns a json data:

```
function fetchCountryCode(sel) {

    var country_id = sel;
    var data = "country_id=" + country_id
   // var baseurl =
    alert(country_id);
    $("#code").html("");
    if (country_id.length > 0) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/register/code",
            data: "country_id=" + country_id,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(html) {
                $("#code").html(html);

            }

        });
    }

}
```

Controller function parsing the data:

```
public function code($countryId)
{
    // Get countries list
    $cId = $_POST['country_id'];
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($cId); exit;
    $code = file_get_contents($this->config->config['api_url'] . 'countries');
    $rawdata = json_decode($code);
   // echo "<pre>"; var_dump($rawdata);

    foreach($rawdata as $item){
        print_r($item->code);
    }
 exit;
    $data['countries'] = $this->load->view('login/code', $code);
}
```

Its is giving me all the countries data but i need to fetch the selected id's data only. I am new to it pls guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array with the only matching id and then echo the result as json.

```
$result = array() ;

foreach($rowdata as item){
    if($item->id == $cId)
           array_push($result, $item) ;
} 

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: i did this: ` $result = array() ;
        foreach($rawdata as $item){

            if($item->id == $cId)
                array_push($result, $item) ;
        }
        print_r($result); exit;` but its printing nothing

Comment: you don't ve a json so

Comment: I think you can get an error from the Ajax function... You selected datatype json